# Is it possible to add MPEG as a splash screen (start up screen) - PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I would like to have some animation on the startup window (which will end till the GUIs get ready) instead of a typical image.

And since the animation is hard to implement with pyqt5 (I don't have experience), I would like to use a **MPEG** format.

And why I want to use **MPEG** instead of **GIF** is because as I know **GIF** is more difficult to produce performant and qualitative animation.

So the question is:

- Is it possible? and how?

I would appreciate any tutorials that can help me in implementation as well.

Comment: You can look into classes in the [QtMultimedia](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia-module.html) module.

Comment: A splash screen should always be a lightweight object, otherwise it would make loading even longer (with the result that the loading will be long not because it's required for the UI, but because it's delayed by the splash, thus making it pointless). Also, unless some threading related operation is required on startup, the UI loading can only happen in the main thread, so the animation will probably *not* be smooth as you'd like it. Then, playing a video requires loading the underlying multimedia module (which includes system libraries), extending the loading time even further.

Comment: If your purpose is to show a smooth and high definition animation, then you should probably reconsider. A splash screen should be fast and minimal, and should hide as soon as possible; a high definition video requires system resources both for loading the backend *and* for playing it. If your program doesn't need multimedia for any other purpose, you would be slowing down the loading for something that is actually *not* necessary for the program itself.

Comment: @musicamante Ah, you're right, displaying a video is not a good choice. Actually, What if I used some animation that it's just about a couple of lines let's say it is a Polygon with fading animation. So in your opinion should I create that animation using QPainter, or it will take time as well, in that case, don't using animation will be a better choice.

Comment: @Moaaz QPainter is used by all widgets, so as long as the animation and the painting are well written, it shouldn't require lots of performances. Consider what written above, though: since the UI loading can only happen in the main thread (which is obviously the same thread of the splash animation), it's highly possible that the animation won't be completely smooth anyway. So, keep it simple, and try to create a *simple* animation that doesn't look *ugly* even if sometimes it freezes while loading. If possible, avoid creating objects at every paint event (pens, gradients, etc).

Comment: If you're going to use basic shapes, a possible intermediate solution could be to use the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html): it's well optimized for performance and as long as you use its primitive items (lines, rectangles, ellipses, but also text and pixmaps), you can rely on its fast C++ implementation while limiting the python code to the bare minimum.